# iOS: Force view reload after locale change

Tags: ios, uiview, localization, uisegmentedcontrol

I have setup my app to support a base internationalization for English and added a local for Spanish.  I'm trying to provide an option to force the app to use a locale select by the user via a segmented control.

What I would like to do is have the screen "refresh" or "redraw" with the new selected locale.

Here is my action for the segmented control:

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender {
   UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
   NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

   NSUserDefaults *prefs;
   prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   if (selectedSegment == 0) {
       [prefs setObject:@"en" forKey:@"language"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       NSLog(@"English");
   }
   else
   {
       [prefs setObject:@"es" forKey:@"language"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       NSLog(@"Spanish");
   }
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My hope is that the screen would refresh and display the selected language view. If I close out the app and restart, it does display new view.

Here is my viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   // get the saved language preference
   NSUserDefaults *prefs;
   prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *stringVal = [prefs stringForKey:@"language"];

   // Make sure we have a valid value
   if (stringVal != nil) {

       // Set the language preference
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:stringVal, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate

       // Turn on the appropriate segment
       if ([stringVal  isEqual: @"en"]) {
           NSLog(@"English");
           languageSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

       } else {
           NSLog(@"Spanish");
           languageSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
       }
   } else {

       // default to English
       languageSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
   }
}
```

I had thought that following would force a screen refresh but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you only want to select appropriate segment? If so, I think every thing is ok

Comment: I want the view to reload upon segment selection.